# Rails jquery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Im trying to implement the following bootstrap layout in my rails project:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

But I can't seem to get the off canvas nav to toggle which appears for smaller screens. I've placed the following javascript in /assets/javascripts/offcanvas.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

And when I check the source code of my page it shows up but it's not working!

```
<script src="/assets/offcanvas.js?body=1"></script>
```

When I paste the script in application.js itself it does work though. But I can't seem to figure out what the problem is in the other situation.

Comment: Does console report any errors?

Comment: You mean by requesting the page while running the server? I don't get any errors that way.

Comment: No, javascript console.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. To check if the script works correctly?

Comment: Yes. If there is something wrong with js itself it should be visible there. If you'll see something there, you will know where to look, as it doesn't look like the error comes from Rails.

Comment: Yeah but the script itself works fine! I've tested it only problem is that sometimes it doesn't work on the webpage itself and sometimes it does.